# what is wrong with my binary search tree validation code?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

**According to the definition, a Binary Tree must satisfy the following conditions:**
 *1. The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than
    the the node's key.

 2. The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node's key.

 3. Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.*

My code is returning ***True*** for the input  ***[10 ,5, 15, #, #, 6, 20]*** but it's incorrect, it must return ***False***.
***The input follows a level order traversal, where '#' signifies a path terminator where no node exists below.***

Here is the tree:

```
         10
        /  \
       5   15
          /  \
         6    20
```

*Here is my code :*

```
    # Definition for a binary tree node.
    # class TreeNode(object):
    #     def __init__(self, x):
    #         self.val = x
    #         self.left = None
    #         self.right = None  


    def isValidBST(self, root)
    """  
    :type root: TreeNode  
    :rtype: bool  
    """  

    if not root:  
        return True  
    else:  
        if root.left and root.right:  
            return root.left.val < root.val < root.right.val and \    
                   self.isValidBST(root.left) and self.isValidBST(root.right)  
        elif root.left and not root.right:  
            return root.left.val < root.val and self.isValidBST(root.left)  
        elif root.right and not root.left:  
            return root.right.val > root.val and self.isValidBST(root.right) 
        else:  
            return True
```

Comment: Could you show what the tree is you are having an issue with in some other manner?  For example, `(val left-subtree right-subtree)`?

Comment: Can you show us how you convert the list to 'root' ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a BST where A is the root value, B is the value at the root of its left subtree, and C is the value at the root of the right subtree under that.  Your code will verify that A > B, and that B < C.  But it does *not* check to see if A > C.

Or, from your example: It checks that 5<10, 10<15, 6<15, and 15<20, but does *not* check that 6>10.

Recall that the definition of a BST talks about *all* nodes in a subtree, not just the root.

Comment: you are right, i was missing on that case. Thanks for your help, i really appreciate it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm doesn't implement frist two conditions properly. You should compare root value with maximum of left subtree and minimum of right subtree.

Alternatively, you can do an inorder traversal of the tree which should be in ascending order in binary search tree.

Comment: yes, comparing root value to the max of left subtree and min of right subtree recursively would be a better approach because a root must be greater than the maximum of left subtree and smaller than the minimum of right subtree. The second approach is quite trivial also. Thank you very much for the idea :)